# Angular, how to make a whole component transparent when use it as an overlay

Tags: javascript, html, angular, overlay, transparent

I am using a component as an overlay when click a button. What's annoying me is that the background color of the component is always white even though the thing I put on the component is transparent. My demo component (css):

```
.blank {
    border-style: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.0);
}
```

html:

```
<div class="blank"><p>blank-component works!</p></div>
```

I only can adjust the foreground and background color of a box containing "blank-component works", but not the whole component as the overlay.

The overlay component is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { BlankComponentComponent } from '../blank-component/blank-component.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-overlay-component',
  templateUrl: './use-overlay-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./use-overlay-component.css']
})
export class OverlayComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog
  ) {
    let observable = new Observable(this.myObservable);
    this.showOverlay(observable);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  myObservable(observer: any) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next("done waiting for 5 sec");
      observer.complete();
    }, 5000);
  }

  showOverlayUntilExecuted(observable: Observable<any>) {
    let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<BlankComponentComponent> = this.dialog.open(BlankComponentComponent, {
    //let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<OverlayDialogComponent> = this.dialog.open(OverlayDialogComponent, {
      panelClass: 'transparent',
      disableClose: true
    });
    let subscription = observable.subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        //handle response
        console.log(response);
        dialogRef.close();
      },
      (error) => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        //handle error
        dialogRef.close();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Where should I look into?

Answer (score 0):

i think there's an issue with the style sbeing applied to the overlay component. when you open the `BlackComponentCompomemnt` as adialog overloay, it's within the dialog container and the styles of teh container are probabyl affecting the appearance of the component.

you need to target the dialog container and set its background to transparent. in your global styles add this

```
/* styles.css or styles.scss */
.transparent-dialog-container .mat-dialog-container {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

and modify your overlay component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { BlankComponentComponent } from '../blank-component/blank-component.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-overlay-component',
  templateUrl: './use-overlay-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./use-overlay-component.css']
})
export class OverlayComponent {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {
    const observable = new Observable(this.myObservable);
    this.showOverlayUntilExecuted(observable);
  }

  // ... Your other methods and logic

  showOverlayUntilExecuted(observable: Observable<any>) {
    this.dialog.open(BlankComponentComponent, {
      panelClass: 'transparent-dialog-container', // Use the CSS class here
      disableClose: true
    });

    // ... Rest of your code
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but seems not working for me. I still see a small box containing "blank-component works!", but its background is still white.

Comment: try adding "!important"... so "background-color: transparent!important;"

Answer (score 0):

In a [MatDialogConfig](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig) you have two properties:

1. `backdropClass`:the class of the background
2. `panelClass` the class of the cdk-overlay-panel.

You should use :

```
//better use const instead of let
const dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TableBasicExample> = this.dialog
            .open(TableBasicExample, {
               backdropClass: 'transparent', //<---is backdropClass
               disableClose: true
            });
```

NOTE you can use also `hasBackdrop:false`

```
const dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TableBasicExample> = this.dialog
            .open(TableBasicExample, {
               hasBackdrop: false, //<---here
               disableClose: true
            });
```